# Usage of last-child in UL/LI css

Tags: css, html-lists, css-selectors

I have a website that I am building, and I am doing a menubar for it.

My problem is that, I created separators between the menus, and I wish that the last menu option would not have the separator.

Code of the CSS:

```
div#menu ul {
top:5px;
position: relative;
list-style-type: none;
height: 80px;
width: 900px;
margin: auto;
}
div#menu li{
float:left;
}
div#menu ul a {
position: relative;
background-image: url(divider.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right;
padding-right: 49px;
padding-left: 49px;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 14px;
color: #001B24;
}
div#menu ul > li:last-child { 
background-image: none !important; 
}
```

This is the Html:

```
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Bemutatkozó</li></a>
 <li><a href="#">Kínálatunk</li></a>
 <li><a href="#">Referenciáink</li></a>
 <li><a href="#">Kapcsolat</li></a>
 <li><a href="#">Előjegyzés</li></a>
 </ul>
```

I tried everything, but the background image wont go away on the last child. Please help :)
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image appears to be on the `a` descendent elements of the `li` elements, not the `li` itself. That said, you could try, instead:

```
div#menu ul > li:last-child a { 
    background-image: none; 
}
```

Comment: Thx for that. Thing is this, last child thing is unknown territory for me. Thx again for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Drupal 7, this worked for me:

```
div#navigation ul#main-menu.links > li:last-child a {
  background-image: none;
}
```